# The more a MLP neural network is trained, the value of correct class should increasingly closer to 1, and the other classes to 0? Is this expected?

Tags: neural-networks

I am using a multilayer perceptron network with the Iris dataset. **This network has 3 output neurons** (to represent the 3 classes of Iris, that is, Iris Versicolor, Iris Virginia and Iris Setosa). Therefore, **the output of this network is a vector of 3 positions (for each class)**. **The criterion I used to determine which class is predicted is
simply the index of this vector that has the highest value.**

I used this neural network presented in this article:
https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-backpropagation-algorithm-scratch-python/

And the Iris dataset: https://github.com/selva86/datasets/blob/master/Iris.csv

I ran several tests experimenting with different amounts of epochs, learning rate, etc. **With the tests I was able to notice the following:**

- **If I train this network with just a few epochs, for example, 1 or 4    epochs**, the result of **all predictions** in both the training and
  test    data **is always 0 or 1, that is, the network always makes
  mistakes    because it always predicts the same value**, which is
  totally expected    as she trained very little.
- **But, increasing the number of epochs, to 20 epochs or more**, I noticed that    the resulting vector output from this neural network
  for the test    data is something like [0.999, 0.996, 0.993] (where
  the highest value was    that of the first index of the vector, which
  represent the first class). In my    test I did, for this sample the
  network was correct saying that the    class was 1, and in fact this
  was the desired class in the test    dataset.
- **However,at last, when training for more epochs, for example, 1000 epochs**, it was also able to generalize to the test data, **but with much
  better output vector**, with the value of the predicted class more
  differentiable from the other values, **for example [0.999, 0.345,
  0.230].**.

In the last test I did, notice that with this large number of epochs, the output vector contained much better values, which for the correct class were increasingly closer to 1, and for the other classes, closer to 0.
Note also that **the values ​​were much more numerically differentiable.**

I had this doubt: the more a multilayer perceptron neural network (MLP) trains, the more the value for the correct class should become increasingly closer to 1, and the value of the other classes closer to 0? Is this expected behavior during training?

Comment: Since the Iris dataset as a ML benchmark quite represents its whole population, the sample error of your trained hypothesis accuracy testing could more or less be an unbiased estimator for its corresponding true error parameter along with likely quite small or practically acceptable variance. You may not need large number of epochs here to tradeoff bias-variance of your MLP model with an appropriate complexity level and weights distribution, do you know the usual ways to balance such bias-variance tradeoff?

Comment: @mohottnad Thanks for answering. I don't know. What are usual ways to balance such bias-variance tradeoff? And how does it work?